# How to get posts published between a date and today?

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts, date

Is it a way to get posts published between a date and today with `query_posts()` ?

Example : All posts published since **2012-04-01**

Thanks

EDIT :

How to add the filter date on this Query Posts ?

```
query_posts( array(  
    array('post'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('post-format-image')
        )
    ),
    'cat' => '-173',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
) );
```

Comment: [Don't use query posts!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/9364) :)

Comment: Don't use query_posts(). Check this -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/7890

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE December 23 2014**

There is a better method using `date_query` property of `WP_Query` class:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array( 
            'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( 'post-format-image' )
        )
    ),
    'cat'           => '-173',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'date_query'    => array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'after'   => '- 30 days'
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Use the [Time Parameters in WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Quoting example from the Codex:

**Return posts from the last 30 days:**

```
// This takes your current query, that will have the filtering part added to.
$query_string = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( 'post-format-image' )
        )
    ),
    'cat'           => '-173',
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);

// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-30 days' ) ) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

---

**Edit**
(in response to the OP's updated question).

[Avoid using query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50761/9364). You can use the above technique to alter your main query (subject to some extra [conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) - is home page, is a page called 'foobar' etc. ):

```
function wpse52070_filter_where( $where = '' , $query ) {
   if( $query->is_main_query() && is_page( 'foobar' ) ){
      // posts in the last 30 days
      $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '-30 days' ) ) . "'";
   }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse52070_filter_where' );
```

Comment: Ok ! So the filter is now in `$query_string`. But how it works with my args in Query_Posts ? (Check my edit @Moraleida)

Comment: @Steffi - see updated answer. I hope you don't mind the addition, Moraleida.

Comment: just added your current query, so you can ditch query_posts right away. :) And thanks @StephenHarris for the quick update!

Comment: Thank you @moraleida ! Amazing ! Just one thing. You said : "Avoid using query_posts." But it is better to use `query_posts()` in templates files (such as **home.php**) than `new WP_Query()`, no ?

Comment: Not really. `query_posts` should be used only to alter the main loop - and a lot of people argue that not even then (there's `the pre_get_posts` filter for that too). I often find myself using only `WP_Query` or `get_posts` for all my queries as they're standalone and can be used multiple times w/o interfering with anything else. Check the linked answers on your comments for a thorough explanation. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to get posts between two dates, then use the before and after parameters in the date_query parameter,

```
$query_string = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', 
  'date_query' => array(
    'column' => 'post_date',
    'after' => '2012-04-01',
    'before' => '2012-04-30' 
  ),
  'tax_query' => array(
      array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => array('post-format-image')
      )
  ),
  'cat' => '-173',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

Answer (score 4):

As of 3.7 you can use date_query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

So the args passed would look like:

```
$query_string = array(
      'post_type' => 'post', 
      'date_query' => array(
        'after' => '2012-04-01' 
      ),
      'tax_query' => array(
          array( 
             'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => array('post-format-image')
          )
      ),
      'cat' => '-173',
      'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```