# Query post for today, if no post get the previous one

Tags: posts, query, date

**EDIT : I answered myself.**

Simple request for you. I am trying to develop a code that search for post for TODAY. If it returns nothing, then get the latest post before today.

For now, I have made a small algorithm to expose your my question.

```
<?php 
            // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array (
                'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
                'year'                   => date('Y'),
                'monthnum'               => date('m'),
                'day'                    => date('d'),
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    // do something
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found (Here I need to make the new request)

                $args_before = array (
                    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
                    'year'                   => date('Y'),
                    'monthnum'               => date('m'),
                    'day'                    => date('d'),
                );

                // Classic query will go here ...
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I start with my first array($args) that search for post for TODAY and then I check if I have results.

The tricky part, if I have no posts, do I need to work in the else{} and how can I acheive to get the previous first post before TODAY?

Do I need to work with `BETWEEN` and `ORDER DESC` ?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a recursion function that will call itself if there's no posts found passing new date to query for..

```
function getDatePosts( $date, $query_args ) {

$query_args['date_query'] = array(
    'year' => date( 'Y', $date ),
    'mounth' => date( 'm', $date ),
    'day' => date( 'd', $date )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
    $date = $date - ( 60 * 60 * 24 );
    $query = getDatePosts( $date, $query_args );
}

return $query;

}
```

And use it in your template:

```
$query = getDatePosts( time(), array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
 // output
endwhile;
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: I will give a look at it! Thx for your collaboration.

Comment: Does this way effect on web loading? I mean this query don't engage all wp_posts table data and just engage 1 day posts?

Answer (score 0):

I founded on this page something that helped me to complete my request.

[How to get posts published between a date and today?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52070/how-to-get-posts-published-between-a-date-and-today?rq=1)

**Use date_query**

```
'date_query'            => array(
                            'column'        => 'post_date',
                            'after'         => '- 30 days'
                        ),
```

As you can see, we can check for column *post_date* and ask them to go backward.

```
            // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array (
                'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
                'year'                   => date('Y'),
                'monthnum'               => date('m'),
                'day'                    => date('d'),
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();

                    // do something
                }
            } else {
                // no posts found
                $args_previous = array (
                    'post_status'           => 'publish',
                        'date_query'            => array(
                            'column'        => 'post_date',
                            'after'         => '- 30 days'
                        ),
                        'order'                     => 'DESC',
                    'orderby'                => 'date',
                    'posts_per_page'         => '1'
                );

                // The Query
                $query_previous = new WP_Query( $args_previous );

                if ( $query_previous->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query_previous->have_posts() ) {
                        $query_previous->the_post();

                        // do something
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Really, you have no post!';
                }
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
```