# Only show posts from the last trailing 12 months

Tags: php, the-events-calendar

I have this query

```
<?php
        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'eventDisplay'=>'past',
            'tax_query' => array(

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'compliance',
                    ),
                        ),

                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'associated_people',
                                'value' => $current_user,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                    )
                ); ?>
```

It calls all events from the past but I need it to only pull past events that have dates from the last 12 months from the current day, is there any way I could do this?

I'm using the events calendar pro

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Do you mean filtering the `post_date` field? Is "current day" = today?

Comment: Ah, I have missed out a vital piece of information! I am filtering the vents calendar at the moment, and I need to only show events that are in the last 12 months starting from the current day

Comment: Please add all information into the question. I guess the event date is stored as a custom field (post meta)? You could try to search this site for similar quesitons.

Comment: Thanks, I have just done that, That's a good idea, thanks for your input :-)

Comment: see this one helpfull : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52070/how-to-get-posts-published-between-a-date-and-today

Comment: I eventually found a point in the right direction, thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in the end -

```
<?php
        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
            'tax_query' => array(

                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'management-leadership',
                    ),
                        ),

                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'associated_people',
                                'value' => $current_user,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                    )
                ); ?>
```