# get orders of today's date

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to get all the orders of the `current date` as the product page loads
for example orders of today's date `2021-01-13`
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493085) but this didn't help me.

Here is my code

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
        'date_query' => array(
        'post_date' => //I want current date orders
        )
    );

    $fmeb_all_orderIds = get_posts($args);
    // loop through $fmeb_all_orderIds
```

how can I get the current date orders, please help.
Thanks :)

Comment: You need to read about the WP_Query class and the Data Parameters - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

Comment: This post helps also: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52072/7968